# Is <meta name="title"> redundant?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, title

The `<title>` tag is displayed to the user of the search engine. Given that it is also what the search engine uses for ranking, why would one need to include a `<meta name="title" content="">` tag?

Comment: Where have you seen this `<meta name="title" content="">` element used? Bear in mind that this could be used internally by the application, not necessarily for SEO benefit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `<meta name="title" ../>` is superfluous.

It is clear, after reading the HTML [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element) of the `meta` tag:

> The meta element represents various kinds of metadata that cannot be
>   expressed using the title, base, link, style, and script elements.

So the meta `title` doesn't provide any additional information to the title tag, and it is not even one of the meta properties recognized by [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

The  tag is used to add information related to our webpage/website. 
When we search for any website on any search engine, SEO technique uses robots to look out for words searched in the meta tag. Therefore to get our page on the first page of any search engine , properly use meta tag. Golden rule of SEO(search engine optimization).
Happy networking...